# Posting object with Vue for Maatwerk Laravel Excel export

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-jetstream

I'm a bit stuck right now. I want to create an export using Maatwerk Laravel-Excel. The user must be able to set some filters. In Vue I will set the selected values when selected. When the button is pressed the user must receive the download.

In Vue:

```
data() {
        return {
            selected: {
                manufacturers: [],
                categories: [],
                seasons: [],
                date: null
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        exportClick() {
            axios.post('/export/', this.selected)
            .then(function (response) {
     
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
    
            });
        },
    }
```

In the Controller:

```
public function export(Request $request)
{
    $name = "test.xlsx";
    return Excel::download(new Export($manufacturers, $categories, $seasons, $date), $name);
}
```

I'm kind of new to developing and I don't know how to access the variables inside the request. I'm also wondering if the download will start with axios. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To access variable inside the request:

```
public function export(Request $request)
{
    // all
    $allRequests = $request->all();

    // single variable
    $date = $request->date;
}
```

Please read laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#introduction

I never download something in Axios.

The simplest way to do it:

```
<a href="/download-excel" download target="__blank">Download Excel</a>
```

Please read this documentation:
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#downloading-a-collection-as-excel

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think my explanation isn't clear enough. The main problem is posting an object and then downloading with Laravel-Excel.
I have made some exports with GET requests, but I need to pass all the selected values so I can't use a GET request right? And is it possible to create an Export from a post request?